# Как сделать проверку на определенный период чисел и буквы

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

**Пояснение:**

Пишу игрового бота - казино. Пользователь вводит `р поставить` после чего идут два аргумента от пользователя `1 - на что ставка` `2 - сумма ставки`. В первом сделал возможность поставить от `0` до `36`. Но как можно сделать, чтобы была возможность поставить на `к - красное` и на `ч - черное`, чтобы в аргумент принималось либо число от 0-36, либо буква и была проверка на правильное указание на что ставка?

**Код:**

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
cur = conn.cursor()

bid = 0
args_bid = message.text.split()[2]
if args_bid:  # На что ставка
    try:
        bid = int(args_bid)
    except ValueError:
        bot.reply_to(message, '❗ Используйте: Рул поставить (0-36/к/ч) (ставка)❗')
        return
    if 0 > bid or bid > 36:
        bot.reply_to(message, '❗ Используйте: Рул поставить (0-36/к/ч) (ставка)❗')
        return

money = 0
args_money = message.text.split()[3]
if args_money:  # Сумма ставки
    try:
        money = int(args_money)
    except ValueError:
        bot.reply_to(message, text='❗ Используйте: Рул поставить (0-36/к/ч) (ставка)❗')
        return

    cur.execute('SELECT balance FROM users WHERE user_id=("%s")' % user_id)
    users = cur.fetchall()

    for user in users:
        balance = user[0]

        if money > balance:
            bot.reply_to(message, text=f'❌ Превышен баланс ❌\n\n Ваш баланс: {balance:,}')
            return

cur.execute('SELECT group_id FROM roulette WHERE group_id=("%s")' % group_id)
group_info = cur.fetchall()
conn.commit()

if len(group_info) == 0:
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO roulette (group_id, start_time) VALUES ("%s", "%s")' % (
        group_id, datetime.datetime.now()))
    cur.execute(
        'INSERT INTO roulette_users (group_id, user_id, bid, bid_money) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % (
            group_id, user_id, bid, money))
    cur.execute('UPDATE users SET balance=balance-("%s") WHERE user_id=("%s")' % (money, user_id))
    conn.commit()

    bot.reply_to(message, text=f'✅ Вы поставили {money:,} на {bid}')

else:
    cur.execute(
        'INSERT INTO roulette_users (group_id, user_id, bid, bid_money) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % (
            group_id, user_id, bid, money))
    cur.execute('UPDATE users SET balance=balance-("%s") WHERE user_id=("%s")' % (money, user_id))
    conn.commit()
    bot.reply_to(message, text=f'✅ Вы поставили {money:,} на {bid}')

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

В качестве одного из вариантов могу предложить делать проверку вхождения введенного пользователем значения в список "разрешенных" к ставке значений:

```
bid = [*[str(x) for x in range(0, 36)], 'к', 'К', 'ч', 'Ч']  # Формируем комбинацию разрешенных к ставке значений (0..36, к, ч)
args_bid = message.text.split()[2]  # Получаем ставку пользователя
if args_bid in bid:  # Проверяем, находится ли ставка в списке разрешенных
    print('ставка принята')  # Действие при успехе
else:
    print('Используйте: Рул поставить (0-36/к/ч) (ставка)❗')  # Действие, если пользователь ввел что то другое
```

Comment: но у меня также идет проверка суммы ставки, мне получается использовать еë в if arga_bid in bid?

Comment: можете использовать такую проверку `if args_bid in bid and message.text.split()[3].isdigit()`

Comment: a вообще такие вещи лучше делать через [FSM](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py), где вы последовательно получаете от пользователя данные: нажимается кнопка -> поступает предложение ввести ставку -> затем предлагается ввести сумму -> полученные данные обрабатываете как хотите, причем на каждом этапе можно делать нормальную проверку введенных данных (ввел ли порльзователь правильную ставку, хватает ли у него баланса и т.д.)